# New point is closest to which old point?

Tags: r

Okay,

Say i have 2 points with x,y coordinates,

```
a<-c(1,1)
b<-c(10,10)
```

Now i want to find which point above is closest to my new point,

```
ce<-(2,2)
```

There has to be a function out there, but knn is too complex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manish's answer is correct. However, you might also be interested in a solution that can be generalized to more than two points. In that case, we first want to create a matrix, where each column in the matrix is one of our points. You can create this matrix however you please. Below is an example

```
> point_1 <- c(1, 6)
> point_2 <- c(2, 4)
> point_3 <- c(-1, -1)
> points <- matrix(c(point_1, point_2, point_3), nrow = 2)
> points
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2   -1
[2,]    6    4   -1
```

Next, I provide a function that calculates the distance from all of these points to a single test point. This function uses the fact that R will recycle vectors when needed.

```
> my_point <- c(1, 1)
> distances <- sqrt(colSums((points - my_point) ^ 2))
> distances
[1] 5.000000 3.162278 2.828427
```

Finally, you can find the point that is closest to your original point by finding the element of this vector that is smallest.

```
> closest_point <- which.min(distances)
> points[, closest_point]
[1] -1 -1
```

Alternatively, you could put all of your points into a single matrix and use the `dist` function to calculate all pairwise distances. However, this will perform more calculations than is necessary.

```
> all_points <- rbind(point_1, point_2, point_3, my_point)
> dist_mat <- dist(all_points)
> dist_mat
          point_1  point_2  point_3
point_2  2.236068                  
point_3  7.280110 5.830952         
my_point 5.000000 3.162278 2.828427
```

Comment: If you use `cbind` when creating the matrix, the names of each point will be preserved as column names. Then you can do `distances[which.min(distances)]` and see the name of the closest point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dist() to calculate distance (euclidean) between two points.

```
> a <- c(1,1)
> b <- c(10,10)
> ce <- c(2,2)

> dist(rbind(x, a))
         x
a 1.414214

> dist(rbind(x, b))
         x
b 11.31371

a is closed to ce.
```